# Keras Illegal Instruction 4

Tags: keras

I have been trying to get Keras working on my laptop running El Capitan but when I attempt to import it I get the following message

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I've looked for solutions, and have tried updating theano, installing mxnet-mkl, and running an older version of numpy (1.13) to avoid a FutureWarning error.  None of these has seemed to fix the issue, though.  I feel like I must be missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing an older version of TensorFlow (1.5 seems to work). AVX2 instructions are now enabled by default in latest TF pip wheels, meaning if your processor doesn't support these instructions, then you will get an illegal instruction error.

Another solution is to install TensorFlow from source, which should detect your processor and configure it accordingly.